# Strategy to implement a complex C# GUI

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

I'd like to create an interactive, simplified version of the Blender node editor to get exposure to complex GUI programming. I have experience with basic GUIs but I want to learn more.

Here's an example of the Blender node editor:
[image: Blender node editor example]

My strategy:

- `C#` for application programming
- Node types represented as subclasses of an abstract `Node` class
- `Winforms` GUI. (I'm unfamiliar with `WPF`, plus I've read integrating `WPF` with external graphics can be difficult.)
- `OpenGL` / `Direct3D` (or similar?) for interacting with nodes and rendering into a `Winforms` panel. This could either be P/Invoked C# or a separate C++ project along with the base C# application. I'm not sure which is better.
- Output a useful representation of node structures into `JSON` for later use

.

I'm looking for some pointers on how to move forward. Does this strategy make sense? What are the watchouts?

For graphics programming, should I use `OpenGL`, `Direct3D`, or go down a different path like custom control painting? Please keep in mind I'm looking to learn, not build a robust production system.

Comment: `integrating WPF with external graphics can be difficult` can you elaborate what you have in mind here? What are external graphics for you? Personally I would go for WPF.

Comment: I'd say that WinForms and complex GUI do not fit. Shure, there is much to learn if you program WPF. You'll need to understand XAML. Only using a forms designer is not enough.¨WPF is for creating complex UI that scales well for different devices. So I think you should consider that

Comment: @thehennyy In this case I consider "external graphics" to refer to using, for example, a separate C++ project to contain the OpenGL graphics engine, vs. combining all aspects into one project.

Comment: You do not need OpenGL or Direct3D. I've written this style of interface using both WPF and WinForms. WPF makes it a bit easier IMO, but the workload is pretty similar unless you're using using an MVVM pattern.

Comment: @RogerN I assume you mean performing all of the painting inside of a custom `Control` object? Have you found this is responsive enough for normal user interaction?

Comment: @natedogg It's easily responsive enough. You don't even need custom "painting" per se, you can use regular UserControls on a Canvas for your nodes and then connect them with Path objects. WPF also has built-in hardware acceleration for drawing.